# How to store large string data into s SQL Server 2005 data base?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have 100000 Ids to store into our DataBase. Id is in string format.each id contain 10 char. So what is the best data type is for this data?

I have been used vrchar(max), text but my problem is not solved.

So please experts help me.

Comment: 100000 is nothing.  What "problem is not solved" by storing them in varchar(max) or even varchar(10)?

Comment: What error message are you getting? What is the insert code and code to create the table structure? We do not undersand what kind of problem you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not just varchar(10), if that is the max. length? that way you avoid any off-row storage. Although you'll need a good reason to store a numeric valued column in a non-numeric column...

Comment: I think question is not clear to you.I have 1000000 ids.so how can i store 1000000 string data into sql server 2005

Comment: Why are you storing 1,000,000 records in one field on one row?  Each data item should be in its own row.  If it is a many-to-one or many-to-many relationship, then you're architecting the data model wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If each id is exactly 10 characters, then use a char(10) field

Comment: well - trouble with char(10) is that every entry gets padded to 10 chars length. So if you store "abc" in the field, you really get "abc       " - which can be a pain to find, later on. I'd prefer VARCHAR(10) - even for just 10 characters.

Comment: which is why I said "If each id is exactly 10 characters"

Answer (score 0):

varchar(10) assuming you have one ID *per row* and *upto* 10 characters

All 100000 in one varchar(max) is simply **wrong**... or have I misunderstood your intention?